# kernel tunables for non privileged user

Tags: sudo, kernel, user-permissions

How can i permit non privileged user to set kernel tunables within specific limit. For instance to let user set **hugepages** up to 40

`sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=40`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using sudo + regexp:

`user    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=[0-4][0-9]`

Comment: Thanks for reply! i've tried to put it into **sudoers** file and got the following error
`sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.nr_hugepages'`

P.S. my distro is Centos 7

Comment: Do you have selinux activated? Try to run setenforce 0 as root then sudo and the command as user

Comment: It looks like it works perfectly with **sudo** in front, Thank you!